# Вырезать тэги из строки

Tags: php

```
<?if($arParams["YANDEX"]):?>
<?
    $my_text = $arItem['full-text'];
    $my_text = '<p style="text-align: justify;"> Міністр Оборони США Ештон Картер вважає, що Росія під управлінням Володимира Путіна несе таку ж небезпеку світу, як терористична організація «Ісламська держава».<br> <br> Виступаючи на базі морської піхоти Кемп-Пендлтон в Каліфорнії, Картер назвав «сумним» розвиток подій в Росії. Він зазначив, що адміністрація США повинна реагувати на дії російського уряду при Путіні, що, на його думку, «<i>ведуть Росію в неправильному напрямку для його власного народу</i>».<br> <br> «<i>Але судячи з усього, це саме той напрямок, в якому Путін хоче їх вести — до чергової конфронтації. Нам просто доведеться стримати це, як в інтересах нашої власної безпеки, так і тому, що у нас є важливі союзники і друзі в цьому регіоні світу. Також, у нас є важливі договірні зобов’язання по лінії НАТО</i>», — сказав очільник Пентагону.<br> <br> За словами Картера, тих викликів, які представляють «Ісламська держава» і теперішня Росія, не існувало ще півтора роки тому. </p> <br> «<i>За останній рік вони сягнули загрозливих розмірів, нам потрібно протистояти їм обом</i>», — зазначив він.<br> <br> Фото ua.krymr.com';
        $arrs = explode('<', $my_text);
        $texter = '';
        foreach($arrs as $key=>$value){
            $brr = explode('>', $value);
            $texter = $texter . $brr[1];
        }
        if(count($arrs) > 1){
            $texts = $texter;
        }else{
            $texts = $my_text;
        }
    ?>
    <yandex:full-text><?echo $texts ;?></yandex:full-text>
<?endif?>
```

Есть строка с тэгами, их нужно вырезать.
Строка выглядит как $my_text второе присвоение.
вычитал что strip_tags для строчных элементов длинной больше строки не работает, написал свой парсер, так вот, сейчас код работает но мне нужно не для константной строки это сделать,а если убрать строку $my_text = ' Мініст ..., которая тут для примера, что в строке получаемой находится - выдаст результат пустую строку.

$arrs = explode('<', $my_text);
Длинна $arrs почемуто = 1. Для всех элементов(
Хотя одна из получаемых строк уже в примере выведена(

И с регулярками и стрип_тэгс работают для определенной переменной, а в цикле, для $my_text = $arItem['full-text']; ничего не работает :(
Просто вообще пустой xml файл выдает, хотя там кроме этого, еще куча полей заполнено, и они корректно всегда отображаются.

Если кто знает в чем проблема, буду благодарен!

Comment: Как насчёт регулярок? preg_replace("~<.*>~U", "", $str); Отлично работает при условии, что нет поломаных тегов и лишних символов "<", ">"

Comment: C Эштоном Картером полностью не согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Функция вам вполне подходит [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)

Пример:

```
$text = '<p style="text-align: justify;"> Міністр ......<br> <br> Фото ua.krymr.com';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Про ограничение, это не для строк а для имен тегов:

> Замечание:
>   Имена тегов в HTML превышающие 1023 байта будут рассматриваться как невалидные независимо от параметра allowable_tags.

Comment: Да я сразу попробовал strip_tags сделать, не получается, для
   $my_text = strip_tags($arItem['full-text']);
Оно тупо выдает с тэгами...
Еще заметил штуку, иногда nbsp; попадаются, в некоторых текстах, иногда тэги...

Comment: Пришлите полный текст который приходит в $arItem['full-text'], поиграюсь, может найду в чем проблема...

Comment: Если вы дадите ваш IP, открою доступ на сайт, там все текста будут и структура более наглядная

Comment: Вот ip: 109.170.9.162

Comment: http://www.grushevskogo5.com/sobitiya/rss/

Comment: Привет, посмотрел xml который ты предоставил, у тебя точно в переменной $arItem['full-text'] есть данные, проверь приходят ли они туда. Если ты используешь SimpleXml то для доступа к наймспейсам таким как <yandex:full-text> надо использовать встроенный метод. Почитай доки по поводу наймспейсов. Если нужно помочь то смогу но попозже так как сейчас на работе и не очень много времени свободного

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением для удаление тегов из текста.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$my_text = '<p style="text-align: justify;"> Міністр Оборони США Ештон Картер вважає, що Росія під управлінням Володимира Путіна несе таку ж небезпеку світу, як терористична організація «Ісламська держава».<br> <br> Виступаючи на базі морської піхоти Кемп-Пендлтон в Каліфорнії, Картер назвав «сумним» розвиток подій в Росії. Він зазначив, що адміністрація США повинна реагувати на дії російського уряду при Путіні, що, на його думку, «<i>ведуть Росію в неправильному напрямку для його власного народу</i>».<br> <br> «<i>Але судячи з усього, це саме той напрямок, в якому Путін хоче їх вести — до чергової конфронтації. Нам просто доведеться стримати це, як в інтересах нашої власної безпеки, так і тому, що у нас є важливі союзники і друзі в цьому регіоні світу. Також, у нас є важливі договірні зобов’язання по лінії НАТО</i>», — сказав очільник Пентагону.<br> <br> За словами Картера, тих викликів, які представляють «Ісламська держава» і теперішня Росія, не існувало ще півтора роки тому. </p> <br> «<i>За останній рік вони сягнули загрозливих розмірів, нам потрібно протистояти їм обом</i>», — зазначив він.<br> <br> Фото ua.krymr.com';
$my_text = preg_replace('%<[\/a-z][^<>]*>%ui', '', $my_text);

print_r($my_text);
```

Comment: С обычной строкой работает четко. Когда подставляю значение из массива, не работает(

Comment: @Jackson, какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: либо никаких ошибок, либо xml файл становится пустой

Comment: @Jackson, сделайте логирование в файл содержимого строки перед отправкой ее в preg_replace. И покажите, что в файле будет записано.